# Querying nearby users with PFQueryTableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview, parse-platform

So I am trying to implement a `PFQueryTableViewController` that queries and returns users near the current user. However when I run this simultaneously on my phone, and on my simulator I am unable to return anything inside of my tables. I have the class connected with a `tableView` in my `storyboard`. Does anyone have any ideas why this isn't working? Here is the bulk of the code for the `PFQueryTableViewController` function.

```
- (id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {

    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {

        self.className = @"User";
        self.keyToDisplay = @"name";
        self.pullToRefreshEnabled = YES;
       // self.paginationEnabled = YES;
    }

    return self;

}

- (PFQuery *) queryForTable {
    PFQuery *locals = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.className];

    if ([self.objects count] == 0) {
        locals.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;
    }
    TSAAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    CLLocation *currentLocation = appDelegate.currentLocation;

    PFGeoPoint *point = [PFGeoPoint geoPointWithLatitude:currentLocation.coordinate.latitude longitude:currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];

    [locals whereKey:@"location" nearGeoPoint:point withinKilometers:0.1],
    [locals includeKey:@"name"];
    [locals includeKey:@"file"];

    return locals;
}
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object{



    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];}

    cell.textLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"name"];
    if ([object objectForKey:@"file"] == nil) {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"profile_default"];
    }
    else {
        cell.imageView.image = [object objectForKey:@"file"];
    }

    return cell;

}
```

Comment: How are you calling this PFQuery which you had returned in the above method?

Comment: I believe that I call this query at the end of the tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath with the "object:(PFObject *)object" at the end. That is what I deduced from the parse documentation. Though I could very well be wrong. Is this wrong? and if so is there another way to do this?

Comment: Your code looks fine. Have you set the class of your viewcontroller in your Storyboard to this class?

Comment: @JamesFrost I have connected the class to my Storyboard. Although I am using a tableViewController in my Storyboard to connect to this class.  is that perhaps an issue?

Comment: `PFQueryTableViewController` is a subclass of `UITableViewController`, if I remember rightly. But the class of your tableViewController in your storyboard **must** be set to `PFQueryTableViewController`.

Comment: @JamesFrost It seems I had my Storyboard set to the class I was implementing the functions from and not to PFQueryTableViewController.

Comment: @JamesFrost I am now getting the error "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'You need to specify a parseClassName for the PFQueryTableViewController.'"  which is probably because I dont have my implementation folders connected to anything. How can I fix this? And thank you for your help I appreciate it a ton. I am still very new to programming.